# Kubernetes Resource Requests and Limits

Tags: kubernetes

I'm new to kubernetes. I'm just wondering is there any downside if i'm set the value for kubernetes container resource requests and limits as max as possible like this?

```
resources:
   limits:
     cpu: '3'
     memory: 1Gi
   requests:
     cpu: '2'
     memory: 256Mi
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set `requests` to the minimum values your pod needs and `limits` to the max you allow it to use. It helps Kubernetes to schedule pods properly.

If the `requests` value is too high, then Kubernetes may not have any node that fulfills these requirements and your pod may not run at all.

Check this link for more details: https://sysdig.com/blog/kubernetes-limits-requests/

Comment: but if I set it like the example I wrote above, do you think there will be any downside effects later? or should it be fine?

Comment: It looks ok, but it really depends on the application you're running. E.g. your service is a Spring Boog Java web service, then `256Mi` may be a little low and what can happen is that your container is started, but you get OOM. On the other hand if your service is a simple Golang web service, then `256Mi` may be high.

Comment: oh okay, then what will happen if I set it too high?

Comment: Nothing, but your pod may not be scheduled if Kubernetes does not find any node which satisfies your `requests`.